# What are the effects of GRANT DELETE?

Tags: sql-server

What is the difference between:

```
GRANT DELETE ON TABLE1 TO ROLE1
```

and

```
GRANT DELETE TO ROLE1
```

One of our DBAs executed the second version by mistake.  I want to be certain I understand all the ramifications.

Comment: To Undo: REVOKE DELETE TO ROLE1

Comment: Wont this remove any other permissions that were correctly assigned before executing that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is table specific. The second allows deletion from any table

Comment: That's what I thought :S